# How to user Schedule Library to run function every minute

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, schedule

When i use **Schedule** library [(library link)](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) to run function every 1 minute. it works fine but my other URL not working. only scheduled function working.

```
#import scheduler library
import schedule
import time    

#update every hour global table no of players and totol payouts
def updateTotalPayoutsAndTotalPlayers():
    try:
        querysetGlobal = Global.objects.filter().first()
        querysetUser = Players.objects.filter(is_active=1).count()
        querysetTotalPayouts = Game.objects.filter(gameStatusId=3).aggregate(Sum('pot'))
        totalPayouts = querysetTotalPayouts['pot__sum']
        # print("total payouts : ",totalPayouts)
        querysetGlobal.totalPlayers = querysetUser
        querysetGlobal.totalPayouts = 0 if totalPayouts==None else totalPayouts

        querysetGlobal.save()
        # print("completed task......")

    except Exception as e:
        print("error updating payouts and no of players : ", e) 


#update globals table called ever one minute
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(updateTotalPayoutsAndTotalPlayers)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

when i removed **while** other API's working. but my schedule won't run.

to run server i used command : **python manage.py runserver**

Comment: You may wanna take  a look at celery https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html, this is designed to run periodic tasks. Also take a look at https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-beat/

Answer (score 0):

```
from celery import shared_task
@shared_task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=10, max_retries=5)
    def my_func(self):
        ***some code***
```

Or try something like that:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=60))
def my_func():
    ***some code***
```

before that install redis server on Linux/Windows/Mac
and make *pip install redis*.

in your settings:

```
# Redis/Celery application definition
REDIS_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
REDIS_PORT = '6379'
BROKER_URL = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 3600}
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
```

Comment: __periodic_task__ is not defined. and when importing from __celery__ it says can not import __periodic_task__

Comment: still getting error : name 'periodic_task' is not defined, can you please share documentation link.

Comment: pip install celery